# Trying to get product Id at checkout

Tags: magento2, products, sku

I'm trying to get the product Id's/SKU's after a customer has hit the purchase button with no success.

```
 $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$checkout = $om->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
    $itemsIds = $checkout->getItems();
// Create connection
    $db = $om->get('Magento\Checkout\Block\Database');
    foreach ($itemsIds as $item)
    {
        $sku [] = $db->getSkuQuery($item);
    }
    echo $sku;
}
```

getItems brings me nothing. Could it be that my method was place after the cart was checked out? If so where would be the best place to invoke it?
If there is a quicker and easier way to get the SKU's that would be awesome to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just replace your code:

```
$sku [] = $db->getSkuQuery($item);
```

with

```
$sku [] = $item->getProduct()->getSku();
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer but my problem was with $item not the function getSku(). meaning that itemIds was null and did not have any information. I added the method to the php file Successvalidator in the checkout module but i fear that the cart has already been flushed by then and i have no idea where to add this method so i can get all the data I need.